# phalcon tag->appendTitle not working when I don't use setTitle in the initialize funciton

Tags: php, oop, phalcon

I'm using a controller base with the following function:

```
...
class ControllerBase extends Controller{

  public function initialize()
  {
    $this->tag->appendTitle(' - Something');
...
```

It only works if I add tag->setTitle inside the initialize function, like this

```
class ContactController extends ControllerBase
{
  public function initialize()
  {
    $this->tag->setTitle('Contact Us');
    parent::initialize();
  }
```

The above produces the title "Contact Us - Something"

But I have some controllers that display different views, and I need to define different titles according to the view I want to show, in that case tag->appendTitle defined in controllerBase doesn't work.

```
class CompetitionsController extends ControllerBase {

  public function initialize()
  {
    parent::initialize();
  }

  public function indexAction()
  {
    $this->tag->setTitle('Search Competitions');
```

The above produces the title "Search Competitions", it doesn't add " - Something".

How can I do this without having to copy $this->tag->appendTitle(' - Something'); in every function.

Comment: add `$this->tag->setTitle('');` to your `initialize()`

Comment: The ControllerBase::initialize is called before  CompetitionsController::indexAction so the ```$this->tag->setTitle('Search Competitions');``` overwrites what was already set.

Comment: Correct @GregoryBurns, I've discovered that appendTitle needs to go after setTitle to work... Is there any workaround to define appendTitle globally?

Comment: @Timothy I've tried that, but didn't work